# How to use MySQL subquery and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, subquery

Thank you in advance. 
I have a table that is like this...

```
Sender_id receiver_id message time_sent
1          2          Hello    07:19:00
2          1          Hi.      07:20:00
2          3          Sup      07:21:00
4          5          wyd      07:18:00
```

I am trying to get all the messages where 2 is the sender or receiver and  then remove the duplicates IDs so I end up with only the last message for each user.
Think like the list of messages on the home page of a chat app.

From my research I know I need some combination of subquery and DISTINCT or GROUP BY, but I cannot wrap my mind around MySQL complex queries. Basic queries I get easily.

This is what I have so far

```
$messages_results = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT * 
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}messages 
    WHERE sender_id = ".get_current_user_id()." OR receiver_id = ".get_current_user_id()."  
    GROUP BY receiver_id, sender_id");
```

Please show me example and explanation if possible. I would really like to understand MySQL complex queries. I'm ready and practicing, but I'm just not getting it. 
Thanks again.

EDIT:
Im expecting

```
Sender_id receiver_id message time_sent
2          1          Hi.      07:20:00
2          3          Sup      07:21:00
```

Comment: Please show us the expected results that corresponds to your sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()` in a subquery to rank records within groups of messages having the same `sender/receiver` value by descending `time_sent`. Then the outer query just filters on the latest record per group:

```
select sender_id, receiver_id, message, time_sent
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by least(sender_id, receiver_id), greatest(sender_id, receiver_id) 
            order by time_sent desc
        ) rn
    from mytable t
    where sender_id = ? or receiver_id = ?
) x
where rn = 1
```

In earlier versions, this can also be achieved with a correlated subquery that returns the maximum `time_sent` for each `sender/receiver` tuple:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    (sender_id = ? or receiver_id = ?)
    and time_sent = (
    select max(time_sent)
    from mytable t1
    where 
        least(t1.sender_id, t1.receiver_id) = least(t.sender_id, t.receiver_id)
        and greatest(t1.sender_id, t1.receiver_id) = greatest(t.sender_id, t.receiver_id)
)
```

In this **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ugahCQLfukenRZmuo8yLjw/0)**, when given `2` as parameter, both queries return:

```
| Sender_id | receiver_id | message | time_sent |
| --------- | ----------- | ------- | --------- |
| 2         | 1           | Hi.     | 07:20:00  |
| 2         | 3           | Sup     | 07:21:00  |
```

Comment: Hi. GMB thanks for answering. I updated with what I'm expecting back.

Comment: @J.F.Bond: I updated my answer accordingly, and added a db fiddle for your reference.

Comment: Yes. I'm am trying them now, but I cannot get it to return anything.  Your fiddle is working so I'm guessing it's on my end. I've changed the table name and IDs. I'll keep messing with it until something happens. I will mark your answer if I can get it to work. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Note @J.F.Bond: you need to replace both question marks with the `id` of the user for which you want to generate the report.

Comment: I've done that. @GMB: I can get it to work up to ```where 
        least(t1.sender_id, t1.receiver_id) = least(t.sender_id, t.receiver_id)
        and greatest(t1.sender_id, t1.receiver_id) = greatest(t.sender_id, t.receiver_id)");
```

Comment: @J.F.Bond: are you getting an error message?

Comment: Thank you @GMB. I've gotten much closer and learned about MySQL least() and greatest() functions. I will keep working on it until I get it. Thanks again.

Comment: @J.F.Bond: welcome!